# How can I display plots in PyCharm?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I have a problem visualizing plots in pycharm, and I haven't found a solution yet.
Does anyone know how to view plots in PyCharm?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
df['Score'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(
    kind='bar',
    title='Count of Reviews by Stars',
    figsize=(10, 5)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you add `plt.show()` at the end of your script?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
df['Score'].value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar', title='Count of Reviews by Stars',
                                                      figsize=(10, 5))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this at the top of your script:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```